# Can not pass properties of MaterialCommunityIcons in a Custom NavigationBar React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, uinavigationbar, react-native-navigation, tabbar

I am trying to pass the Material Community Icon props in a custom TabBar but they don't work. I have react native 0.6.5.

My custom TabBar is:

```html
function MyTabBar({
  state,
  descriptors,
  navigation,
  iconColor,
  iconName,
  iconSize,
}) {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flexDirection: "row",
        position: "absolute",
        bottom: 25,
        backgroundColor: "#182028",
        borderRadius: 25,
        marginHorizontal: 5,
      }}
    >
      {state.routes.map((route, index) => {
        const { options } = descriptors[route.key];

        const label =
          options.tabBarLabel !== undefined
            ? options.tabBarLabel
            : options.title !== undefined
            ? options.title
            : route.name;

        const isFocused = state.index === index;

        const onPress = () => {
          const event = navigation.emit({
            type: "tabPress",
            target: route.key,
            canPreventDefault: true,
          });

          if (!isFocused && !event.defaultPrevented) {
            // The `merge: true` option makes sure that the params inside the tab screen are preserved
            navigation.navigate({ name: route.name, merge: true });
          }
        };

        const onLongPress = () => {
          navigation.emit({
            type: "tabLongPress",
            target: route.key,
          });
        };

        return (
          <TouchableOpacity
            accessibilityRole="button"
            accessibilityState={isFocused ? { selected: true } : {}}
            accessibilityLabel={options.tabBarAccessibilityLabel}
            testID={options.tabBarTestID}
            onPress={onPress}
            onLongPress={onLongPress}
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
              marginVertical: 10,
              borderRadius: 1,
              borderColor: "#333B42",
              height: 50,
            }}
          >
            <View
              style={{
                borderRadius: 5,
                backgroundColor: colors.turquoise,
              }}
            >
              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                name={iconName}
                color={iconColor}
                size={iconSize}
              />

              <Text style={{ color: isFocused ? "#673ab7" : "#222" }}>
                {label}
              </Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
}

export default MyTabBar;
```

On the AppNavigation:

```html
  <Tab.Navigator
    initialRouteName={"Home"}
    tabBar={(props) => <MyTabBar {...props} />}
  >
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={HomeNavigatorAirBnb}
      options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons
            iconName={"rocket"}
            iconColor={color}
            iconSize={size}
          />
        ),
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    />
  </Tab.Navigator>
```

My TabBar looks like this. The icon is not rendering. I have also tried to hardcode the icon properties with all tree properties but still the same. What I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Which icon library are you using?

Comment: MaterialCommunityIcons

Comment: The proper usage for it is  <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />. There's no need to add an Icon to the back of your props.

Comment: Same result! I am not passing the props for the icon, and use the default <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />. Maybe the {color} and the {size} are not defined, no value being a custom TabBar?